# Inscribed n edge of ellipse.

Tags: geometry

[image]

> Give an ellipse: $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1,\qquad a>b>0$$
>   Give the point $X=(a,0),Y=(0,b)$.
>
> Then draw $n$ ($n \ge 2$) segments $XA_1=A_1A_2=A_2A_3=\cdots=A_{n-1}Y$, and draw $n+1$ segments $XB_1=B_1B_2=B_2B_3=\cdots=B_nY$, here the $A_i,B_i$ ($i=1,2,\cdots,n$) must be on the ellipse and which part of the first quadrant, and $YXA_1A_2\cdots A_{n-1}, YXB_1B_2\cdots B_n$ is convex.
>
> Then, is $XA_1 > XB_1$ true?

When the ellipse is a circle, I can use central angle to prove that. but ellipse, I do not know how to do.

Comment: Is there anything that prevents $A_1$ from lying on the arc between X and $B_1$? I don't think so, but the question seems slightly mangled in the "...and which part of the first quadrant..." part: that does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @Nick Thank you for your attention. With intuition, I think it is right, but I can not prove. so I think maybe it should be described in more detail. after the proof, maybe some conditions are superfluous.

Comment: I don't think you have enough conditions to decide one way or the other. For the points shown in the diagram, $XA_1 \gt XB_1$ but if you can put $A_1$ between $X$ and $B_1$, the opposite is true.

Comment: @Nick yes you are right, I just noticed it. if there is on $A_i$ between $B_1$ and $X$, or between $B_nY$, by distance formula $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$, we have $XA_1<XB_1$. in diagram ($n=2$), it means $XA_1<XB_1=YB_2<YA_1$, so it is wrong.